# Client ECC SSL Certificate contains "unknown named curve"

Tags: ssl, netty, java, elliptic-curve

Question precontext:
I am working in an existing library that uses SSL with the netty framework on a remote server. I am running into an SSL/TLS handshake error. The error is as follows:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: java.io.IOException: Unknown named curve: 1.2.840.10045.3.1.1
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.checkThrown(Handshaker.java:1345) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.checkTaskThrown(SSLEngineImpl.java:519) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:799) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:767) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:624) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:982) ~[netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:908) ~[netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:854) ~[netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:249) ~[netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:149) ~[netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:333) ~[netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:319) ~[netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:787) ~[netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:130) ~[netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511) ~[netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468) ~[netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382) ~[netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354) ~[netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:116) ~[netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:137) ~[netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: java.io.IOException: Unknown named curve: 1.2.840.10045.3.1.1
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeMessage$CertificateMsg.<init>(HandshakeMessage.java:451) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.processMessage(ServerHandshaker.java:222) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:901) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:841) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:839) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$DelegatedTask.run(Handshaker.java:1273) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.runDelegatedTasks(SslHandler.java:1015) ~[netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:927) ~[netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateParsingException: java.io.IOException: Unknown named curve: 1.2.840.10045.3.1.1
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertInfo.<init>(X509CertInfo.java:171) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.parse(X509CertImpl.java:1781) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.<init>(X509CertImpl.java:196) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.security.provider.X509Factory.engineGenerateCertificate(X509Factory.java:97) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.security.cert.CertificateFactory.generateCertificate(CertificateFactory.java:339) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeMessage$CertificateMsg.<init>(HandshakeMessage.java:449) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unknown named curve: 1.2.840.10045.3.1.1
    at sun.security.ec.ECParameters.decodeParameters(ECParameters.java:197) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.security.ec.ECParameters.engineInit(ECParameters.java:319) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.security.AlgorithmParameters.init(AlgorithmParameters.java:293) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.security.x509.AlgorithmId.decodeParams(AlgorithmId.java:139) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.security.x509.AlgorithmId.<init>(AlgorithmId.java:114) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.security.x509.AlgorithmId.parse(AlgorithmId.java:382) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.security.x509.X509Key.parse(X509Key.java:168) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.security.x509.CertificateX509Key.<init>(CertificateX509Key.java:75) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertInfo.parse(X509CertInfo.java:705) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertInfo.<init>(X509CertInfo.java:169) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    ... 27 common frames omitted
```

Now, here was my approach to try solving this issue at hand. This remote server requires client authentication and that certificate is the one that uses elliptic curves (using a client certificate with different public key algorithms and signature algorithms does not cause the error meaning that the client certificate is at fault here). I ran

```
openssl x509 -in <client_cert> -text -noout
```

```
The client certificate is as follows:
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 3585039615565000225 (0x31c09e8937746e21)
    Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA1
        Issuer: <ISSUER>
        Validity
            Not Before: Dec  1 23:01:26 2014 GMT
            Not After : Nov 26 23:01:26 2034 GMT
        Subject: 1.3.6.1.4.1.41387.1.1=18B43000004C627B
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: id-ecPublicKey
                Public-Key: (192 bit)
                pub:
                    04:dc:ca:07:76:de:28:91:b8:94:16:08:12:01:85:
                    24:a5:a5:5e:48:84:aa:2b:f8:3a:fa:87:f1:30:70:
                    f3:7b:01:68:6a:f6:29:56:c7:17:60:71:fe:b7:c0:
                    d1:d5:1c:ad
                ASN1 OID: prime192v1
                NIST CURVE: P-192
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:FALSE
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature, Key Encipherment
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage: critical
                TLS Web Client Authentication, TLS Web Server Authentication
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:
                <SUBJECT KEY IDENTIFIER>
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier:
                keyid: <KEY ID>

    Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA1
         <SIGNATURE GOES HERE>
```

This leaves me under the impression that the NIST P-192 curve is not being recognized by JDK SSL library. The JDK version I am running is 1.7.0_79. I don't know how to proceed fixing this. Any ideas?

Comment: Also using different NIST curves results in the same error

Comment: If I remember correctly then Java 1.7 doesn't include all the OID's as aliases in the ECC provider. You can probably resolve this by somehow configuring Bouncy as default for ECDSA signatures or by upgrading to 1.8. Too little time to verify this though.

Comment: Did anyone try the solution from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31971499/ecdhe-cipher-suites-not-supported-on-openjdk-8-installed-on-ec2-linux-machine to copy `libsunec.so` from Oracle JDK?

Answer (score 0):

This might be related to an encryption issue, rather than an SSL issue. Have you tried using the [unlimited strength jurisdiction policy files](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html)?

Comment: The unlimited strength jurisdiction policy files are installed on the server