# Set up Netty-with TLS handsake with ECC and RSA client certificate auth

Tags: ssl, netty, bouncycastle, jce, jsse

I am working on a remote server that uses Netty to perform client authentication with a TLS handshake through the Netty SSLHandler library. This S/O question gives a bit: [Set up Netty with 2-way SSL Handsake (client and server certificate)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9573894/set-up-netty-with-2-way-ssl-handsake-client-and-server-certificate)

Now, the question I have about this system is that the Server requires a TrustManager to initialize a SSLContext. From what I observe this uses the SunJSSE provider. Now after setting up this implementation, I got it working with RSA client certs. Now, I am having trouble using ECC client certs as SunJSSE cannot recognize them (I think Java SE 7 include SunEC as a provider. But SunEC is a SunJCE implementation and not a SunJSSE one and thus cannot be used as a provider for TrustManager). So, how do I proceed. I heard Bouncy Castle can recognize these certs, but I still cannot instantiate a TrustManager with BC as the provider.

Edit: Also if there is no way to use TrustManagers, should I do the entire handshake only use BouncyCastle's API's and not netty's libraries? That seems off though.
This is my other S/O question that shows the stack trace: [Client ECC SSL Certificate contains "unknown named curve"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30603680/client-ecc-ssl-certificate-contains-unknown-named-curve)

Comment: Sorry that you didn't receive an answer. Yes, generally you need to add ECC functionality *before* you can update the protocols that use it. I assume this works for newer versions of Java. Is this question still applicable to you?