# CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9824) against server that support TLSv1.2

Tags: ios, swift, ssl, tls1.2

I have a very simple tomcat webserver that I have set up to work with TLSv1.2 which is confirmed by using curl

```
$ curl --verbose https://{my-servers-dns}:8443/
*   Trying {my-servers-ip-address} ...
* Connected to dev.a-b.fit ({my-servers-ip-address}) port 8443 (#0)
* TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
* Server certificate: {my-servers-dns}
* Server certificate: Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2
* Server certificate: Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority - G2
> GET / HTTP/1.1
...
```

However, if I run this very simple swift code to make the same GET request

```
let url = NSURL(string: "https://{my-servers-dns}:8443/")!
let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in
    if let response = response {
        print("Response: \(response)")
    }
    else {
        print("Response: nil")
    }
})
```

When I do this I get the following 2 errors

```
CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9824)
NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9824)
```

Googling these errors suggest that the issue is that my app can not connect with TLSv1.2. However, I would have thought that the curl request shows that TLS 1.2 is supported.

Comment: That said it is highly likely that the issue is at my server end as using `https://www.google.com` works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> * TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
> ```

This is a DHE cipher suite curl uses here. This might mean that your server does not support ECDHE cipher suites because usually these are preferred compared to DHE.

From the [iOS 9 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-9.0/):

> DHE_RSA cipher suites are now disabled by defaults in Secure Transport for TLS clients. This may cause failure to connect to TLS servers that only support DHE_RSA cipher suites. ...

This means if your server only supports DHE ciphers then the connection will fail in the default setup of an iOS 9 client. This is likely the case here.

Comment: To add the required ECDHE to tomcat there some very simple instructions here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31971499/ecdhe-cipher-suites-not-supported-on-openjdk-8-installed-on-ec2-linux-machine