# ECDSA isn't suported in Java 1.8?

Tags: java, ecdsa

I think that on my machine (Debian 10, linux, JAVA 1.8 OpenJDK), ECDSA isn't supported by Java.

Why? Because this line throws exception:

```
KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("ECDSA");
```

However, if I change ECDSA to RSA for example, no exception is raised then.

I'm using Debian GNU/Linux as mentioned. Should I install some package or something like that?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using Oracle's jdk or openjdk or some other?  I've noticed differences across different jdks previously.

Comment: Hey Taylor3, I'm using openjdk

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31973241/829571

Comment: As far as I'm aware, you should use `"EC"` for the name, not `"ECDSA"`

Answer (score 6):

As a `KeyFactory`, it appears that the name is just `"EC"`, not `"ECDSA"`.

---

You can list the available key factories using the following code (Java 5+):

```
for (Provider provider : Security.getProviders()) {
    System.out.println(provider.getName());
    for (Service service : provider.getServices()) {
        if (service.getType().equals("KeyFactory"))
            System.out.println("  " + service.getAlgorithm());
    }
}
```

I've run it on various Java versions on my Windows 7 machine. As you can see below, Java for Windows comes with the following Key Factories:

- DSA
- RSA
- EC   *(Java 7+)*
- RSA
- DiffieHellman

*Java 9.0.1*

```
SUN
  DSA
SunRsaSign
  RSA
SunEC
  EC
SunJSSE
  RSA
SunJCE
  DiffieHellman
SunJGSS
SunSASL
XMLDSig
SunPCSC
JdkLDAP
JdkSASL
SunMSCAPI
SunPKCS11
```

*Java 1.8.0_151*

```
SUN
  DSA
SunRsaSign
  RSA
SunEC
  EC
SunJSSE
  RSA
SunJCE
  DiffieHellman
SunJGSS
SunSASL
XMLDSig
SunPCSC
SunMSCAPI
```

*Java 1.7.0_79*

```
SUN
  DSA
SunRsaSign
  RSA
SunEC
  EC
SunJSSE
  RSA
SunJCE
  DiffieHellman
SunJGSS
SunSASL
XMLDSig
SunPCSC
SunMSCAPI
```

*Java 1.6.0_45*

```
SUN
  DSA
SunRsaSign
  RSA
SunJSSE
  RSA
SunJCE
  DiffieHellman
SunJGSS
SunSASL
XMLDSig
SunPCSC
SunMSCAPI
```

*Java 1.5.0_22*

```
SUN
  DSA
SunRsaSign
  RSA
SunJSSE
  RSA
SunJCE
  DiffieHellman
SunJGSS
SunSASL
```