# Does OpenJDK 1.8 support elliptic curve cryptography?

Tags: java, cryptography

Does OpenJDK 1.8 support elliptic curve cryptography?

The API is there but the SunEC implementation seems to require a library that is enabled only for the Oracle JDK.

Comment: I think it was introduced in java-7... http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk7/features/#f73

Comment: That said, more information [here](https://bodhi.fedoraproject.org/updates/FEDORA-2016-9fd9fc27d8).

Comment: And even more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39884696/589259). It seems to depend on the build :(

Comment: What are you aiming for? Android or desktops? The problem is different depending on the platform.

Comment: I want to run it on Alpine Linux

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does.

Have a look here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html