# How to make openjdk 11 to support elliptic curve cryptography algorithm?

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, cryptographicexception

Getting error "javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Could not generate ECDH keypair" when tried to invoke https URL in java application.It worked fine with Oracle JDK 1.8.0.152.It is not working when we migrated to Openjdk 11.

How to make openjdk 11 to support elliptic curve cryptography algorithm?

Note: We use windows 10 server, Tomcat8 and we use trusted CA certificate

Comment: Possible duplicate: [ECDHE cipher suites not supported on OpenJDK 8 installed on EC2 Linux machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31971499/ecdhe-cipher-suites-not-supported-on-openjdk-8-installed-on-ec2-linux-machine) -- Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39884696/1241334).

Comment: Above link has a bouncy castle provider solution which suits only for OpenJDK8, we don't seem to have a solution for Openjdk11

Comment: Have you tested the **Oracle** version of JDK 11?  [The license](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/terms/license/javase-license.html) does allow for testing.  If it works with the Oracle JDK, you'll know the problem is likely in the difference(s) between the Oracle and OpenJDK versions.  If it *doesn't* work with the Oracle JDK 11, you'll know the problem is likely in the difference in version from 8 to 11.  You'll at least know where to start looking.