# SSLHandshakeException only when using RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, ssl, resttemplate, sslhandshakeexception

I'm using Java 8, trying to post https third party (other subdomain works), works with postman, but using `RestTemplate` throws `SSLHandshakeException`

```
new RestTemplate().postForEntity("https://external-host.com" ,new HttpEntity<>(null, new HttpHeaders()), String.class);
```

I have JCE Unlimited jars in jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\security\policy\unlimited folder and I have bouncy castle bcpkix-jdk15on and bcprov-jdk15on version 1.55

Exception:

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "https://external-host.com": Received fatal alert: handshake_failure; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:785)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:711)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForEntity(RestTemplate.java:468)
...
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:353)
SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:353
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:141)
DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:141
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
MainClientExec.java:380
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
MainClientExec.java:236
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
ProtocolExec.java:184
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
RetryExec.java:88
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
RedirectExec.java:110
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
InternalHttpClient.java:184
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
CloseableHttpClient.java:82
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
CloseableHttpClient.java:55
    at org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.java:87)
HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.java:87
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:66)
AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:66
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:776)
RestTemplate.java:776
    ... 42 more
```

Same output using other [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072585/disabling-ssl-certificate-validation-in-spring-resttemplate) configuring RestTemplate as:

> ```
> TrustStrategy acceptingTrustStrategy = (x509Certificates, s) -> true;
> SSLContext sslContext = org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(null, acceptingTrustStrategy).build();
> SSLConnectionSocketFactory csf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext, new NoopHostnameVerifier());
> ```

SSL log:

```
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1645533027 bytes = { 229, 64, 215, 234, 240, 91, 46, 176, 144, 108, 104, 176, 6, 192, 147, 200, 69, 213, 196, 106, 125, 235, 5, 167, 51, 215, 144, 174 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA256withDSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA224withDSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA
Extension server_name, server_name: [type=host_name (0), value=external-host.com]
***
ajp-nio-8009-exec-32, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 211
ajp-nio-8009-exec-32, READ: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
ajp-nio-8009-exec-32, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
ajp-nio-8009-exec-32, called closeSocket()
ajp-nio-8009-exec-32, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
08:42:43.535 [ajp-nio-8009-exec-32] TRACE o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Failed to complete request
```

**EDIT** I download `cer` file from site, added to Java's cacerts and created p12 file, and tried using the following code, but still handshake exception

```
KeyStore clientStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        clientStore.load(new FileInputStream(utils.getStoreProperty("./external.p12")),
                "MYPASS".toCharArray());

        SSLContextBuilder sslContextBuilder = new SSLContextBuilder();
        sslContextBuilder.useProtocol("TLSv1.2");
        sslContextBuilder.loadKeyMaterial(clientStore, "MYPASS".toCharArray());
        TrustStrategy acceptingTrustStrategy = (X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) -> true;
        sslContextBuilder.loadTrustMaterial(null, acceptingTrustStrategy);
        SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslConnectionSocketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContextBuilder.build());
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
                .setSSLSocketFactory(sslConnectionSocketFactory)
                .build();
```

The following output for `openssl s_client -connect host:443` as suggested
@dave_thompson_085 , @yan

```
WARNING: can't open config file: /usr/local/ssl/openssl.cnf
CONNECTED(000001A4)
depth=3 C = US, O = "The Go Daddy Group, Inc.", OU = Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority
verify error:num=19:self signed certificate in certificate chain
---
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA256
Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-256, 256 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 5814 bytes and written 433 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
    Session-ID: A4966A2268EE5CCFA25DEE734DC980D01DF40A4763A4DF3CD19ADA49FF9AD90E
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: 58BE6AF39E3DB3CBF3166A286550F2333028E66A9CC59AE886EAA777BAEA82A21D318E89746B97B1BFE0E3E7BF60F5E1
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 300 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - 25 c2 24 26 c2 8f d1 6d-32 5e 2f f6 40 95 af d6   %.$&...m2^/.@...
    0010 - 02 de 28 3e 34 ae 47 96-2c 6a 87 2e 61 e6 fd a2   ..(>4.G.,j..a...
    0020 - 75 3b 3c 3b b2 ee 3c 16-ba e5 49 1c 18 f6 a1 16   u;<;..<...I.....
    0030 - e3 4e 7b 6f 48 5d e7 e3-03 df c5 86 45 81 12 5b   .N{oH]......E..[
    0040 - 4e d7 27 da f5 cd ed 18-6d 41 00 55 7a 8e 62 54   N.'.....mA.Uz.bT
    0050 - 31 75 90 3c aa 2a f9 2b-51 c2 c0 10 5d ca 02 6f   1u.<.*.+Q...]..o
    0060 - 51 0e e0 62 6d 94 12 bd-85 4b 01 88 dc 5d 90 ad   Q..bm....K...]..
    0070 - 30 53 8c 09 a7 01 d9 d7-1b 89 ec 77 35 93 9f ae   0S.........w5...
    0080 - b1 00 c7 ba 1c ea 84 77-36 bf 58 59 7a 78 44 f2   .......w6.XYzxD.
    0090 - 77 55 f4 41 2b dd 3c 54-02 38 ae 37 ec 8a c6 10   wU.A+.<T.8.7....
    00a0 - 6e d5 23 0a 05 5c 19 9f-02 4d 9a 0a 1c 9a be 2e   n.#..\...M......

    Start Time: 1645945411
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 19 (self signed certificate in certificate chain)
```

**EDIT** I followed @taleb [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31971499/ecdhe-cipher-suites-not-supported-on-openjdk-8-installed-on-ec2-linux-machine) , but same handshake exception remains

> Add the bcprov-.jar to /usr/lib/jvm/jre/lib/ext

> Edit /usr/lib/jvm/jre/lib/security/java.security adding the following line to the list of providers:

> ```
> security.provider.6=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
> ```
>
> (I added it as the 6th entry but you can add higher in the order if you prefer)

Restarted my application

Comment: is it possible Postman has SSL validation turned off?  If you access the site in any browser is the certificate trusted? or possibly run`openssl s_client -connect external-host.com:443` to see the certificate presented. you can also start the app with `java  -Djavax.net.debug=all` to see what's happening https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html.  https://access.redhat.com/solutions/973783

Comment: @Yan postman ssl validation is on, updating question with debug all output

Comment: (@Yan: _received_ handshake_failure is _never_ due to mistrust of the server cert) OP: Many things _can_ cause handshake_failure and cannot be distinguished from the alert itself. The best approach to check server log(s) to see what _it_ says is the problem. If you can't do that, get a network trace of the successful postman handshake -- or use `openssl s_client -connect host:443` (as suggested) plus if below 1.1.1 `-servername host` and if that works add `-debug` -- and compare _every significant field_ of the working case to your non-working case.

Comment: You could also run openssl with a specific cipher (as explained [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/93143/how-to-pass-cipher-list-to-openssl-s-client)) to check if the server accepts any of your Java cipher suites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please, be aware that the cipher suites described in your debug output doesn't show the cipher suite that was actually used by `openssl`, `ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384`. In fact, they don't include any cipher suite that requires AES 256. It may not be of relevance, but it may be a symptom of any misconfiguration, and can explain why the handshake is failing. As indicated in the [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SupportedCipherSuites) when describing Java 8 supported cipher suites:

> Cipher suites that use AES_256 require installation of the JCE
> Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files.

As a consequence, please, be sure you installed and properly configured the [JCE Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jce-all-downloads.html).

As indicated by @dave_thompson_085 in his excellent comment, only Oracle Java 8 below 8u161 requires adding the unlimited policy, as stated in [Appendix C](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html#AppC) of the aforementioned Oracle documentation.

The JCE Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files are bundled into the JDK since [JDK 8u151](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/8u151-relnotes.html#JDK-8157561), but the `unlimited` policy was not defined as [the default one](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/8u161-relnotes.html#JDK-8170157) since JDK 8u161.

In JDK 8u151 or 8u152, as stated in [one](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/8u151-relnotes.html#JDK-8157561) of the previous cited links, and explained as well by @dave_thompson_085 - thank you very much again, in order to make the `unlimited` version of the JCE the one that should be used, you need to define the system property `crypto.policy`. From the docs:

> This release introduces a new feature whereby the JCE jurisdiction
> policy files used by the JDK can be controlled via a new Security
> property. In older releases, JCE jurisdiction files had to be
> downloaded and installed separately to allow unlimited cryptography
> to be used by the JDK. The download and install steps are no longer
> necessary. To enable unlimited cryptography, one can use the new
> `crypto.policy` Security property. If the new Security property
> (`crypto.policy`) is set in the `java.security` file, or has been
> set dynamically by using the `Security.setProperty()` call before
> the JCE framework has been initialized, that setting will be
> honored. By default, the property will be undefined. If the
> property is undefined and the legacy JCE jurisdiction files don't
> exist in the legacy `lib/security` directory, then the default
> cryptographic level will remain at 'limited'. To configure the JDK
> to use unlimited cryptography, set the `crypto.policy` to a value
> of 'unlimited'. See the notes in the `java.security` file shipping
> with this release for more information.

The issue is not present in OpenJDK.

As an alternative solution, as suggested in [this related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31971499/ecdhe-cipher-suites-not-supported-on-openjdk-8-installed-on-ec2-linux-machine), probably using an alternate provider like BouncyCastle could be of help as well.

Comment: *"One thing you could try is configuring Apache HttpClient to trust the server certificate"* As @dave_thompson_085 stated in a comment, the handshake occurs *before* the validation of the server cert.

Comment: *"depending on the specific JDK 8 version you are using, TLS 1.0 and 1.1 may be disabled"* The log provided in the question shows that TLS 1.2 is being used, so that's not the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback @Olivier. I think the answer try providing as much information as possible, at least it was my intention. I tried to indicate how to debug the TLS session, it links to several related SO questions with information that I think it could be valuable. You are right, TLS 1.2 is shown in both traces, the one from Java and the one from `openssl`, so probably it is not the issue: I edited the original answer to include that information, with the idea to give further advice, but I will remove it now. Sorry, I didn't realize the comment from Dave: as I told, I just

Comment: try providing a working configuration to try to shed some light in the issue. I will wait for some feedback from the OP, but remove the answer if necessary. Again, thank you very much for the feedback, I appreciate it a lot.

Comment: @Olivier I redacted the answer from scratch. Again, thank you very much for pointing out me my initial error, I appreciate it a lot.

Comment: Good catch. Nit: only _Oracle_ Java 8 _below 8u161_ requires adding the unlimited policy, as stated more exactly in Appendix C of your first link, and on [this newer download page](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jce-all-downloads.html) instead of the one you linked. _OpenJDK_ (once it became available separately from Sun/Oracle) did not have the policy issue.

Comment: Thank you very much @dave_thompson_085, and thank you very much for your excellent comment. I included those references in the answer. Please, excuse me for initially not realizing the comment you posted on the question. Again, thank you very much!

Comment: I have JCE Unlimited jars in jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\security\policy\unlimited folder and I have bouncy castle bcpkix-jdk15on and bcprov-jdk15on version 1.55

Comment: I follow @taleb answer in linked answer, but same handshake exception remains

Comment: @user7294900+ 8u151/2 is unique; the policy files are _present_ in the install (you don't need to download) but _disabled_; as the release note says, you must **_change_ crypto.policy=unlimited in JRE/lib/security/java.security**. Using another provider like Bouncy does NOT bypass the policy limit, and the Q (and _correct_ A) you link is about a missing _algorithm_ (EC) not low strength.

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback @user7294900. As indicated in the [documentation I linked](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/8u151-relnotes.html#JDK-8157561) If you are using JDK 8u151, you need to configure the system property `crypto.policy` to a value `unlimited` in order to enable JCE Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files. This setting is not the default until JDK 8u161. Can you try? I am sorry, I will update the answer to clarify that point.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. That is great user7294900, I am happy to hear that the answer was helpful and you manage to solve the problem. @dave_thompson_085 thank you very much for your new comment, I think we posted roughly the same information at the same time!! Thank you very much for your help, I appreciate it a lot.

Comment: Thank you, @jccampanero
I had this problem for hours and nearly went even more insane.
I tried importing certificates, which of course didn't work. After I saw your post, I updated the JDK8 to a newer version, which worked. Putting  `crypto.policy=unlimited` in `java.security` didn't work for me.

I upgraded the JDK from `1.8.0_111` to `1.8.0_181`

Comment: You are welcome @98percentmonkey. That is nice, I am very happy to hear that the answer was helpful and you were able to solve your problem.